# Error with cubepoints. Showing page not found

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I've installed the bbpress and cubepoints plugins in my client's site. Everything else is working fine, except the points table. Whenever I try to visit the mysite.com/members/username/points , it shows page not found.

I've installed bbpress and cubepoints in some other client's site, but then they were working fine. But now it's now. Any idea why it is so? And any solution?

I'm using wordpress 3.5.1
Buddypress 1.7.2
Cubepoints 3.2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably this is a problem with buddypress 1.7. Many people has found this error. But the solution is very easy. You just have to add a stdClass in your bp-cubepoint-core.php file.
Go through this [LINK](http://voidcanvas.com/resolve-cubepoints-page-not-found-error-in-buddypress-1-7-upgrade/) to get the step by step flow.